# nodejs fetch implementation using superflous "then"?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I just started using the library "node-fetch". In the documentation there a serveral examples on how to use the library:

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

All the examples are written in this style of concatenated then-calls.

Couldn't I just have one single then-call and be done with it?

Like this?

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.json());
    });
```

Whats the advantage of having multiple then-calls?

Comment: [No](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

Comment: ahh, res.json() returns a promise.. and thats exactly the promise that executes the second "then" when it is resolved..

Comment: This is when async/await pattern shines:
`var res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github'); console.log(await res.json());`

Comment: @KrzysztofSuszka assuming that is within the body of an `async` function.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - of course, and assuming that you use node version which supports async/await :)

Comment: ES2017/ES8 is the current standard, so that's something that can be safely assumed. If you want to write an answer regarding `async`/`await`, feel free to do so.